# Rsyslog to PostgreSQL works fine but not all columns are filled

Tags: postgresql, rsyslog

I configured correctly to store the syslog messages in PostgreSQL as shown in this image, but ntseverity, importance, eventsource, etc are null:

[image: PostgreSQL and rsyslog message]

This is my configuration until now:

```
## Configuration file for rsyslog-pgsql
### Changes are preserved

module (load="ompgsql")
*.* action(type="ompgsql" server="localhost" db="syslog" uid="rsyslogu" pwd="*********")
```

Seems a template has to be created as shown in:
https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/ompgsql.html

How can I set the template for those extra columns to be filled?
Does someone have the remaining columns in the template?

```
template(name="sql-syslog" type="list" option.sql="on") {
  constant(value="INSERT INTO SystemEvents (message, timereported) values ('")
  property(name="msg")
  constant(value="','")
  property(name="timereported" dateformat="pgsql" date.inUTC="on")
  constant(value="')")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your fields are empty because in the insert statement you only send two fields.

Try somethig like:

```
$template SQLWithProcessID,"insert into SystemEvents (Message, Facility, FromHost, Priority, DeviceReportedTime, ReceivedAt, InfoUnitID, SysLogTag) values ('%msg:R,ERE,1,FIELD:([a-zA-Z\/]+)(\[[0-9]{1,5}\])*:--end%', %syslogfacility%, '%HOSTNAME%', %syslogpriority%, '%timereported:::date-pgsql%', '%timegenerated:::date-pgsql%', %iut%, '%syslogtag:R,ERE,1,FIELD:([a-zA-Z\/]+)(\[[0-9]{1,5}\])*:--end%')",sql

module(load="ompgsql")
*.* :ompgsql:10.40.30.10,rsyslog,rsyslog,rsyslog;SQLWithProcessID
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Frank, your syntax looks a little bit different from -> https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/ompgsql.html (see Example 3). I have not yet tried your suggestion, I will give a try a little bit later